# using ajax to change contents in a span of a different page

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

this is a beginner question. 
How do you use ajax to change contents in a span of a different page?

For example, I have two div's one for menu and the other for content.

The menu is called via ajax, so the list of menu is within a span. Then, I want the menu to change the content page via ajax, but the span is not within the menu page.

How should I achieve this?

Comment: Can you give a code sample? html, javascript, etc...

Comment: Are you using frames? what do you mean by "not on the same page"?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement this scenario would be to use the jQuery AJAX functions to manipulate your HTML.

First, you would load your menu HTML using the `$.get` function. Then, in the callback function to the `$.get` (which runs after the menu HTML is loaded), we give the menu some action that updates the content area with another AJAX request:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get('/url/that/returns/menu', function(returnedHTML){

        // load the #menu div with the 
        // HTML from the AJAX request
        $("#menu").html(returnedHTML);

        // make the menu links update the content area
        $("#menu li a").click(function(){

            // use the href of the menu link 
            // as the content URL
            $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(returnedHTML){

                // load the #content div with the 
                // HTML from the AJAX request
                $("#content").html(returnedHTML);
            });

            // prevent actual link click
            return false;
        });
    });

});
</script>
```